# Can I use ON UPDATE on a MySQL Table for String - VARCHAR Column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am developing a web application, where my database is updated through the application Front End.
However, sometimes, due to some errors/ support, I do update my database from queries. 
Like, for **Last Modified Time** column, the timestamp is automatically updated using the, 
 **'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'**, so I have accurate information regarding time of update.

Similarly, is there a way, I can change a column which stores **Last Modified By** (username) of the user, using the **'ON UPDATE'** or anything similar on the **VARCHAR field**, so that, whenever it is updated from the BackEnd, the **Last Modified By** column is automatically updated as **'SYSTEM'**.

Now the database has correct time of update, but **Last Modified By** column, stores the username of the user who actually last updated it from the Front End and not something that says it was modified through a query, which is causing a bit of confusion.

**Hence, doing this will help me avoid confusion that the Entry was modified from the backend and not the application. 
As I read in many places, the ON UPDATE was only used on TimeStamps and did not find anything similar to UPDATE Varchar fields.**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use a trigger.

Comment: Oh.. I am more into Java right now and learning SQL, as it is required for my project. Thanks. I will look into Triggers.

Comment: I assume your app connects using one userid/password so how would the database know which app user is doing the update as that (i would hope) will not be the user that the app connects to the database as?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: And then of course once you have knowledge of which user did the last update, someone will say why cant we know who did the previous update .. and the one before that! and then you are into a completely different requirement